# Making RDoc Ruby Gem Default on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rdoc

I've recently installed RDoc version (2.4.3) through Ruby gems to replace the one shipped with Mac OS X (version 1.0.1). Unfortunately, I can still only use RDoc 1.0.1 when I call run "rdoc" at the command line. rdoc -v returns:

```
RDoc V1.0.1 - 20041108
```

I tried amending the $PATH variable to point the first entry to the RDoc 2.4.3 folder but no luck. I couldn't find anything about this online either, so I thought I'd ask here.

Cheers!

Update:

Running "`gem list -d --version 1.0.1 rdoc`" returns:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rdoc (2.4.3)
    Authors: Eric Hodel, Dave Thomas, Phil Hagelberg, Tony Strauss
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/rdoc
    Homepage: http://rdoc.rubyforge.org
    Installed at: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

    RDoc is an application that produces documentation for one or more
    Ruby source files
```

Therefore, it's definitely the Mac OSX version of RDoc that's interfering with the Gems version.

Update 2:

I found out, using:

```
`bash --debugger rdoc`
```

that the old version of RDoc was in /opt/local/bin. I deleted it and added my gems directory to my $PATH

```
`export PATH=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/`
```

I now have a fresh working copy of the latest RDoc!

Answer (score 2):

This problem tells you that your two versions are installed in different gem repositories.

Try this:

```
gem list -d --version 1.0.1 rdoc
gem list -d --version 2.4.3 rdoc
```

This will give you detailed information on where the gems are installed. If you can, uninstall the old version.

```
gem uninstall --install-dir /old/gem/repository --version 1.0.1 rdoc
```

If you installed the new version in a nonstandard place, you may need to add that repository's bin directory to your path, and add that directory to your `GEM_PATH` environment variable. So in your `.login` or `.bash_profile` or whatever:

```
PATH = $PATH:/new/gem/repository/bin
export PATH

GEM_PATH = $GEM_PATH:/new/gem/repository
export GEM_PATH
```

You can also set `GEM_PATH` in a `~/.gemrc` file, but that's not always read by command-line tools.

Comment: Thanks Sarah,
The issue is not with two versions of RDoc installed by Ruby Gems conflicting; the version of RDoc that came with Leopard on my Mac is conflicing with the RDoc installed from Ruby Gems.

I ran gem list -d --version 1.0.1 rdoc. It returned:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
rdoc (2.4.3)
    Authors: Eric Hodel, Dave Thomas, Phil Hagelberg, Tony Strauss
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/rdoc
    Homepage: http://rdoc.rubyforge.org
    Installed at: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Comment: Hmm. I'd still recommend removing the old version. If it's not a typcial gem install I'd say just delete it. Another thing to check, though it sounds like maybe you have, is that /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin is in your path.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on Windows running Instant-Rails.  In the end, I just renamed my `ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc` directory to `rdoc.bak` and from then on my rake tasks ran correctly with the new gem rdoc.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought...in Linux we would usually create a link  (i.e. /opt/local/bin/rdoc) that points to the binary that's missing in the existing path. In your case we'd do something like this:
ln -s /opt/local/bin/rdoc /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rdoc

This way the $PATH variable stays a little less cluttered, and you have more control over which binaries you're using.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

works for me out of the box using RVM (Ruby Version Manager)